# UPNP Forwarding WPF

Tags: wpf, upnp, ports

I'm trying to make a port forwarding utility in WPF, I have already made one in WinForms (Looks horrible :D) and I know I used the Microsoft NatUPNP library that is installed by default. I was wondering

A) If NatUPNP library can be used in WPF; and

B) If not, is there a widely used alternative?

For the life of me I can't find the library in any of the toolbox options in WPF nor can I find it to import it using the same calls as my WinForms application:

```
Imports NATUPNPLib
```

Thanks!

Comment: Of course you can use it in a WPF application! WPF is just the user interface technology, the code running under the hood is still .NET code, like it does in your Forms application.

Comment: Did you forgot to add the library into your project references? Does the library involves graphical components too? What version of .NET do you use?

Comment: TBH I can't remember how I added NatUPNPLib to my old project. Yes the library will involve a GUI. I'm using .NET 4.5 in VS2012 Professional.

EDIT: NVM, found my old project and I checked the references, there is a custom reference there. I'll try importing that file :D

Comment: This COM library definitely has some isssues. It shows differents members depending on the .NET version you use and it also gives me compiler errors when trying to build basic examples.

Comment: I completely agree. I've noticed that every 10 or so times I run my program, it will throw a NullReferenceException for the mapping collection.

Comment: So, in the last week, have you found any alternative to NATUPnP.dll ?  I am also having a doosey of a time trying to find anything RECENT from Microsoft that supports or encapsulates UPnP..  NATUPnP.dll uses COM and I would love to avoid using COM if at all possible in my C# WPF program.

Comment: @Curtis Sadly I have not found an alternative. I may look up an alternative soon, however, I only needed the NATUPNP library to make a quick port forward utility to bypass the Admin-Locked router :D. I will update this question if I do find a new UPnP alternative (Will most likely look up today due to my inability to focus on current projects!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said in my last comment, I did some research almost immediately :D

I found 2 links on SourceForge:

**Andrea UPNP Suite (.Net)** - http://sourceforge.net/projects/andrea-upnp/?source=navbar

**Platinum UPNP (C++ may include other frameworks)** - http://sourceforge.net/projects/platinum/?source=navbar

I have not tested these out yet (Going out), but I will test when I get home and update this answer with regards to how at least the Andrea Suite faired (I don't do C++)